# bean definition is not loading into spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I defined the beans definition in country-sg.xml file which I placed in the src/main/resources

Created the root-context.xml and imported above file as , I added root-context file web.xml file.

country-sg.xml file is not loading into context.

Can anyone help how to load this configuration file.

Thanks in advance.

root-context.xml file :

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kachakayala" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <import resource="classpath*: /country-sg.xml"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

country-sg.xml file:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="sg" class="com.kachakayala.services.CountrySg"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the Bean ***sg*** in the application context, you have to scan the the configuration class ***country-sg.xml*** first. You can achieve this by adding the annotation `@ComponentScan("package-of-your-config.xml")` at your main class definition header.